# Data showing up in BigQuery View, but disappearing when exported to a Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a view saved that has a table full of correct data, and whenever I run the query everything shows up just fine.

Below are the results when querying the view:

[image: Results when running the query / within the view]

And here are the results when I try sending it to a table (text fields are there, but nearly every other field is nulled):

[image]

All of the underlying text fields are still present, but anything involving a number is nulled out.

This is kind of baffling to me, since all I'm trying to do is move the data that I know is being collected correctly into a table on a scheduled sync (that had been running fine for months until recently), but now I can't do this simple process or find any resources online about this issue. The exact same issue happens when I try using the underlying View query into a table as well.

Comment: I suspect that output is just presented in different order than when you just do simple select. So double check content of whole destination table by previewing it or selecting from it - I feel you will find what you are looking for

Comment: No, the output order is confirmed to be the same, I just didn't want to include personally identifiable information.  The nulls are appearing for every row in the dataset

Comment: Did you compared the schema of the old and new table ?

Comment: I tried re creating the scenario in my project and it worked fine. how are you sending your data from view to table?